# Get end of week using PHP

Tags: php, date

How can I return the end of the week using PHP?  I wanted to return an array of dates in the following format:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Friday 17 April 2015
    [1] => Friday 24 April 2015
    [2] => Friday 1 May 2015
    [3] => Friday 8 May 2015
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123 no, I've tried googling but can't manage to find anything like this.

Comment: So your end of week is always a Friday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I simply create a [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) starting from the next Friday from today. With a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) of 7 days and until the next month)

```
<?php

    $today = (new DateTime())->modify("next Friday");
    $interval = new DateInterval("P7D");
    $end = (new DateTime())->modify("next month");
    $period = new DatePeriod($today, $interval, $end);

    foreach($period as $date)
        echo $date->format("l j F Y") . "<br />";

?>
```

output:

```
Friday 17 April 2015
Friday 24 April 2015
Friday 1 May 2015
Friday 8 May 2015
```

And for next time if you need todo something with dates see this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Rizier's answer, but using PHP [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php):

```
function fridays() {
    $begin = new DateTime('First friday of this month');
    $end = new DateTime('First friday of next month');

    $interval = new DateInterval( 'P1W' );
    $daterange = new DatePeriod( $begin, $interval ,$end );

    foreach($daterange as $date){
        yield $date;
    }
}


foreach(fridays() as $date){
    echo $date->format("l j F Y"), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: A nice example how you can use php generators :)!